# SQLiteDatabase login functionality

Tags: java, database, sqlite, authentication

I have created an activity where the user is prompted to enter their username and password, which is then checked against the database and if the return is true, it will log them in.

I have a **login** method in my **DB.java** class, which is a public boolean that returns true or false depending on if it's matched.

I then have a **login** class to handle the form.

**DB.java**

```
public boolean Login(String username, String password, SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException
    {
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});
    if (mCursor != null) {
    if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
    return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends Activity  {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login); 

        final EditText usernameET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
        final EditText passwordET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordET);      
        final Button loginBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBTN);
        DB db = new DB(this);   

        loginBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usernamee = usernameET.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordET.getText().toString();      
                ***CHECK LOGIN HERE***
            }
        });      
    }    
}
```

Basically I have tried using the Login method in **Login.java** from **DB.java** like so

```
db.Login(username, password, db);
```

However I guess it's recognising the second 'db' as the class, not the database. So do I need to declare and SQLiteDatabase to put in as the second 'db' or am I doing this completely wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Login(username, password, db);
```

Here the first db is an object of DB class... 
The second should be an object of sqlitedatabase(According to method definition of Login)..
But in the the above code both refer to objects of DB class..
So declare and sqlitedatabaseobject .

```
SQLiteDatabase database;
db.Login(username, password, database);
```